# ReactJS, passing data between siblings

Tags: reactjs

Can someone, please, point me in the right direction?

I have 3 components in my `app.js`file:

```
componentA
componentB 
componentC
```

I guess they are siblings, no parent/child relationships here.

Components A and B are 2 input forms.
Both inputs are for numbers (3 digit numbers).

Component C is the button.

Once I click on the button I need to get input values from components A and B (so would be 2 numbers), do some if/else statements and return some result.

My question is what's the best way to pass data from components A and B into the C?

Comment: The preferred choice will be to initialize their state in the parent component and pass the get and set methods through props. if structure is complex use some global state like redux with redux-form.

Comment: Simon, you should not be guessing that they are a `sibling` component. You need to be sure about it. In React, there is a term called `lifting state up` means in case you need to share the state between sibling /child components then maintain the state at the common `ancestor`

Answer (score 0):

As the React doc says, if two components need to have access to the same state, the solution is to put the state in the closest common ancestor.

In the case of your form, the button needs to read the states from each input to submit the form. So each input's state should be in the parent of the button and the two inputs.

Here is one example :

```
const Form = () => {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState('')
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState('')

  return (
    <>
      <Input value={value1} onChange={event => setValue1(event.target.value)}/>
      <Input value={value2} onChange={event => setValue2(event.target.value}}/>
      <SubmitButton onClick={() => submit({value1, value2})}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

If you need to pass input values through too many props, you can use a context, a state management library (zustand, jotai, ...) or a form library (Formik, react-hook-form, ..).